# Gsettings Remove Desktop Icons Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, trash, desktop-icons

I used to use `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false` to remove desktop icons from Ubuntu 18.04. But this no longer works on Ubuntu 20.04. Why is it not working?

**Edit** 
I don't want other tools that would help me achieve the goal. I just want to know why its not working.

Comment: Ubuntu has both releases with the format *yy.mm* (eg. 20.04) and *yy* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 20), the latter don't use `apt-get` which is used by the main *yy.mm* format releases such as Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  Please clarify your releases (there is no Ubuntu 20, and the closest Ubuntu Core 20 has GNOME running inside a *snap* so configuration is a little different, or do you mean Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as tagged and described which is a different product to Ubuntu with a *yy* format name).

Comment: OK. It is 20.04 LTS, which is why I chose the tag

Comment: Please correct your heading & remove the ambiguity of product/releases.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use the command line, perhaps the GUI interface would be better:

1. Install Gnome Tweaks (if you haven’t done so already)
   `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`
2. Open the application
3. Navigate to the Desktop Icons
4. Toggle the icons off

Changes take effect instantly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know how to get around it. I just don't understand why it doesn't work as it used to. Thanks anyway